# Retroactive named branching in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

Is there a way to associate a bunch of Mercurial changesets with a named branch after they have been committed, i.e. retroactively ?

Answer (score 16):

I just wanted to do this, and here’s the solution I found.
A year has passed since the question was originally asked, this might explain why I can now find a solution.
It has the disadvantage that you create an extra revision in the process, but this wasn’t too bad for me.

First, you go back to where you want to create the branch.
In my case, I actually wanted to start a new root (because I wasn’t very sensible when I started the repository, but anyways), so I’m updating to null. You probably want to start somewhere else, it depends on your situation.

```
$ hg update null
```

Then, create the branch.

```
$ hg branch blah
$ hg commit -m "Created blah branch."
```

Then, we rebase all the commits we made onto our new branch:

```
$ hg rebase -s SOURCE -d DEST
```

The SOURCE here should be the first commit you made in the commits you want to create the branch from, and the DEST should be the commit where the branch was created (the one we committed above).

Comment: This works (I think), but has the potential problem that it doesn't play nicely if you've shared your repository with anyone (as @tonfa indirectly notes).  As the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) notes, _You should not rebase changesets that have already been shared with others. Doing so will force everybody else to perform the same rebase_

Comment: For those working in mercurial hg, you need to enable to the rebase extension in Settings.

Comment: I like this answer - have been looking for "retroactive branching" for a long time - and felt motivated to provide slightly ckeaner instructions (below, in addition to, the original.)

Comment: I guess that nobody liked my slightly cleaner instructions.  Which basically amount to saying "don't get confused by hg update null".  //  In detail:  hg update -r Parent-of-Base-of-Branch; hg branch Proper-Branch-Name; hg ci -m ...; hg rebase -s Where-Branch-should-have-started -d Proper-Branch-Name // although I do hg rebase -s ... -d . // when I am already there.

Comment: WARNING: I just did this to rename a branch. That worked.  But it also renamed all of the task branches that were simple loops off the sequence being renamed.

Answer (score 4):

No, branch names are part of the changeset (it's really like a label you add to the commit), it means the changeset hash depens on the branch name.

So the only way to change it retroactively is by rewriting history (which doesn't play well if you pushed your changes elsewhere, since you'll have to rewrite every repo which has the changes).

To rewrite history, you could use for example mq.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution but, without re-writing history; you could tag the last change set in the unnamed branch. If you never rebranch from this the tag should surfice. If you do need to rebranch you can move on to a named branch after the tagged changeset.