# How to create branches retrospectively

Tags: mercurial

Now many may think I have over complicated the problem or completely lost the plot, but

We adopted Mercurial last year,  and moved all our processes over. I wanted to make this as clean as possible and not worry about how did things before.

We have multiple projects working on different releases all at the same time, I had to find an adoption route for Mercurial that had minimal impact on those projects and then a route to  wean people off PVCS in stages.

All is well, but I have a small issue to deal with namely support work  that is being applied to PVCS that I need to merge back into Mercurial.

I did not have the foresight to create every branch I would need , but I want to creat some branches now.

I want to save a snapshot of the code stored in PVCS in Mercurial, by putting put it in a branch , but I don't have a parent  branch to apply it to .

So 
I  have Branch "Version 5" this is based on revision "0",  how can I create branch "Version 3" now , and then later perhaps Branch "Version 2" or "Version 4", whilst showing the ancestory is not desparately important it would be nice.

Comment: I've read your question twice, and still don't understand what's the problem and what's the goal. Care to refine the question?

Comment: As I read the question, the OP wants to put already-committed changesets onto a branch (as in 'ooops, I should have been doing this on a branch') (or at least, that's what I think I want to do, which is why I found this question).  [There's an existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354941/) which seems relevant, but I suspect the answer is 'no, you can't do that neatly'.